# node and Error: EMFILE, too many open files

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos

For some days I have searched for a working solution to an error

> Error: EMFILE, too many open files

It seems that many people have the same problem. The usual answer involves increasing the number of file descriptors. So, I've tried this:

```
sysctl -w kern.maxfiles=20480
```

The default value is 10240. This is a little strange in my eyes, because the number of files I'm handling in the directory is under 10240. Even stranger, I still receive the same error after I've increased the number of file descriptors.

Second question:

After a number of searches I found a work around for the "too many open files" problem:

```
var requestBatches = {};
function batchingReadFile(filename, callback) {
  // First check to see if there is already a batch
  if (requestBatches.hasOwnProperty(filename)) {
    requestBatches[filename].push(callback);
    return;
  }

  // Otherwise start a new one and make a real request
  var batch = requestBatches[filename] = [callback];
  FS.readFile(filename, onRealRead);
  
  // Flush out the batch on complete
  function onRealRead() {
    delete requestBatches[filename];
    for (var i = 0, l = batch.length; i < l; i++) {
      batch[i].apply(null, arguments);
    }
  }
}

function printFile(file){
    console.log(file);
}

dir = "/Users/xaver/Downloads/xaver/xxx/xxx/"

var files = fs.readdirSync(dir);

for (i in files){
    filename = dir + files[i];
    console.log(filename);
    batchingReadFile(filename, printFile);
```

Unfortunately I still recieve the same error.
What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 115):

For when [graceful-fs](https://github.com/isaacs/node-graceful-fs) doesn't work... or you just want to understand where the leak is coming from.  Follow this process.

(e.g. graceful-fs isn't gonna fix your wagon if your issue is with sockets.)

From My Blog Article: http://www.blakerobertson.com/devlog/2014/1/11/how-to-determine-whats-causing-error-connect-emfile-nodejs.html

### How To Isolate

This command will output the number of open handles for nodejs processes:

```
lsof -i -n -P | grep nodejs
```

```
COMMAND     PID    USER   FD   TYPE    DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
...
nodejs    12211    root 1012u  IPv4 151317015      0t0  TCP 10.101.42.209:40371->54.236.3.170:80 (ESTABLISHED)
nodejs    12211    root 1013u  IPv4 151279902      0t0  TCP 10.101.42.209:43656->54.236.3.172:80 (ESTABLISHED)
nodejs    12211    root 1014u  IPv4 151317016      0t0  TCP 10.101.42.209:34450->54.236.3.168:80 (ESTABLISHED)
nodejs    12211    root 1015u  IPv4 151289728      0t0  TCP 10.101.42.209:52691->54.236.3.173:80 (ESTABLISHED)
nodejs    12211    root 1016u  IPv4 151305607      0t0  TCP 10.101.42.209:47707->54.236.3.172:80 (ESTABLISHED)
nodejs    12211    root 1017u  IPv4 151289730      0t0  TCP 10.101.42.209:45423->54.236.3.171:80 (ESTABLISHED)
nodejs    12211    root 1018u  IPv4 151289731      0t0  TCP 10.101.42.209:36090->54.236.3.170:80 (ESTABLISHED)
nodejs    12211    root 1019u  IPv4 151314874      0t0  TCP 10.101.42.209:49176->54.236.3.172:80 (ESTABLISHED)
nodejs    12211    root 1020u  IPv4 151289768      0t0  TCP 10.101.42.209:45427->54.236.3.171:80 (ESTABLISHED)
nodejs    12211    root 1021u  IPv4 151289769      0t0  TCP 10.101.42.209:36094->54.236.3.170:80 (ESTABLISHED)
nodejs    12211    root 1022u  IPv4 151279903      0t0  TCP 10.101.42.209:43836->54.236.3.171:80 (ESTABLISHED)
nodejs    12211    root 1023u  IPv4 151281403      0t0  TCP 10.101.42.209:43930->54.236.3.172:80 (ESTABLISHED)
....
```

**Notice the: 1023u (last line)** - that's the 1024th file handle which is the default maximum.

Now, Look at the last column.  That indicates which resource is open.  You'll probably see a number of lines all with the same resource name.  Hopefully, that now tells you where to look in your code for the leak.

If you don't know  multiple node processes, first lookup which process has pid 12211.  That'll tell you the process.

In my case above, I noticed that there were a bunch of very similar IP Addresses. They were all `54.236.3.###`  By doing ip address lookups, was able to determine in my case it was pubnub related.

### Command Reference

Use this syntax to determine how many open handles a process has open...

#### To get a count of open files for a certain pid

I used this command to test the number of files that were opened after doing various events in my app.

```
lsof -i -n -P | grep "8465" | wc -l
```

```
# lsof -i -n -P | grep "nodejs.*8465" | wc -l
28
# lsof -i -n -P | grep "nodejs.*8465" | wc -l
31
# lsof -i -n -P | grep "nodejs.*8465" | wc -l
34
```

#### What is your process limit?

```
ulimit -a
```

The line you want will look like this:

```
open files                      (-n) 1024
```

#### Permanently change the limit:

- tested on Ubuntu 14.04, nodejs v. 7.9

In case you are expecting to open many connections (websockets is a good example), you can permanently increase the limit:

- file: /etc/pam.d/common-session *(add to the end)*

  ```
    session required pam_limits.so
  ```
- file: /etc/security/limits.conf *(add to the end, or edit if already exists)*

  ```
    root soft  nofile 40000
    root hard  nofile 100000
  ```
- restart your nodejs and logout/login from ssh.
- this may not work for older NodeJS you'll need to restart server
- use  instead of  if your node runs with different uid.

Comment: How can you change open files limit?

Comment: ulimit -n 2048 to allow 2048 files open

Comment: This is the most descriptive and correct answer. Thank you!

Comment: I have rare numbers. `lsof -i -n -P | grep "12843" | wc -l` == **4085** but `ulimit -a | grep "open files"` == **(-n) 1024**
any clue how I could have more opened files than max limit?

Comment: limits.conf and ulimit did not work for me, however this did: https://superuser.com/questions/1200539/cannot-increase-open-file-limit-past-4096-ubuntu

Comment: Since @blak3r's blog appears to be down, here's a link to his article on the wayback machine. https://web.archive.org/web/20140508165434/http://www.blakerobertson.com/devlog/2014/1/11/how-to-determine-whats-causing-error-connect-emfile-nodejs.html

Super helpful and a really great read!

Comment: Thank you very much! This was the only solution that worked for me. It's interesting that the script(s) throwing errors were really only watching a few files. Any guidance on why a script using the `fs` module to watch about 8 files might be breaking things in this way?

Answer (score 79):

Using the [`graceful-fs`](https://github.com/isaacs/node-graceful-fs) module by Isaac Schlueter (node.js maintainer) is probably the most appropriate solution. It does incremental back-off if EMFILE is encountered. It can be used as a drop-in replacement for the built-in `fs` module.

Comment: Saved me, why is this not the node default?  Why do I need to install some 3rd party plugin to solve the issue?

Comment: I think, generally speaking, Node tries to expose as much to the user as possible. This gives everyone (not just Node core developers) the opportunity to solve any problems arising from the use of this relatively raw interface. At the same time, it's really easy to publish solutions, and download those published by others through npm. Don't expect a lot of smarts from Node itself. Instead, expect to find the smarts in packages published on npm.

Comment: That's fine if it's your own code, but plenty of npm modules dont use this.

Comment: This module solved all my issues! I agree that node appears to be a little raw still, but mainly because it's really hard to understand what is going wrong with so little documentation and accepted right solutions to known issues.

Comment: how do you **npm** it? how do I combine this in my code instead of the regular fs?

Comment: This didn't make a difference for me.

Answer (score 55):

I am not sure whether this will help anyone, I started working on a big project with lot of dependencies which threw me the same error. My colleague suggested me to install `watchman` using brew and that fixed this problem for me.

```
brew update
brew install watchman
```

Edit on 26 June 2019:
[Github link to watchman](https://github.com/facebook/watchman)

Comment: This helped me at least. On a react-native project the bundler can either open the files natively or (if it is installed) use watchman to do it in a way that's nicer to the operating system. So it can be a big help - it's documented in the react-native CLI quickstart for macOS even: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html - cheers!

Comment: It works for me! mac m1 big sur

Comment: I did `which node`. I went to XCode, my app, Build Phases, found `Bundle React Native code and images` and changed `node`, to the output of `which node`.

Comment: @Slackware Can you be a bit clearer in what you commenting here? Are you trying to explain your problem or you talking about the solution?

Comment: @bh4r4th I tried `brew update; brew reinstall watchman` in all possible manners. For me, as an M1 user, what worked was to change which node binary xcode was using.

Comment: @Slackware Are you sure, your `homebrew` setup is done correctly? I remember we had issues setting up homebrew on one of our co-developers laptop. I have a system upgrade soon at my workplae, thinking of getting the new MAC M1 chip one. Hopefully I can try reproducing your issue. :fingerscrossed

Comment: I understand that a reinstall works for some people. It didn't work for me. If you want, you can change the node version that xcode is using. Otherwise, M1 works just fine

Comment: This helped on MacOs Monterey (12.2.1) on M1

Answer (score 26):

I did all the stuff above mentioned for the same problem but nothing worked. I tried below it worked 100%. Simple config changes.

#### Option 1: Set limit (It won't work most of the time)

```
user@ubuntu:~$ ulimit -n 65535
```

Check the current limit

```
user@ubuntu:~$ ulimit -n
1024
```

#### Option 2: Increase the available limit to e.g. 65535

```
user@ubuntu:~$ sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Add the following line to it

```
fs.file-max = 65535
```

Run this to refresh with new config

```
user@ubuntu:~$ sudo sysctl -p
```

Edit the following file

```
user@ubuntu:~$ sudo vim /etc/security/limits.conf
```

Add the following lines to it

```
root soft     nproc          65535    
root hard     nproc          65535   
root soft     nofile         65535   
root hard     nofile         65535
```

Edit the following file

```
user@ubuntu:~$ sudo vim /etc/pam.d/common-session
```

Add this line to it

```
session required pam_limits.so
```

Logout and login and try the following command

```
user@ubuntu:~$ ulimit -n
65535
```

#### Option 3: Just add this line

```
DefaultLimitNOFILE=65535
```

to `/etc/systemd/system.conf` and `/etc/systemd/user.conf`

Comment: option 2 is rather long, and hoped option 3 work, but it isn't for my ubuntu 18

Comment: Debian Bullseye sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf fs.file-max = 65535, I have used this fix multiple times and only done this part of option 2 which has always fixed the problem.

Comment: Also, if you are not a root, you need to replace root with '*' during editing /etc/security/limits.conf

Answer (score 11):

Like all of us, you are another victim of asynchronous I/O. With asynchronous calls, if you loop around a lot of files, Node.js will start to open a file descriptor for each file to read and then will wait for action until you close it.

File descriptor remains open until resource is available on your server to read it. Even if your files are small and reading or updating is fast, it takes some time, but in the same time your loop don't stop to open new files descriptor. So if you have too many files, the limit will be soon reached  and you get a beautiful **EMFILE**.

There is one solution, creating a queue to avoid this effect.

Thanks to people who wrote [Async](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html), there is a very useful function for that. There is a method called [Async.queue](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#queue), you create a new queue with a limit and then add filenames to the queue.

Note: If you have to open many files, it would be a good idea to store which files are currently open and don't reopen them infinitely.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const async = require("async")

var q = async.queue(function(task, callback) {
    console.log(task.filename);
    fs.readFile(task.filename,"utf-8",function (err, data_read) {
            callback(err,task.filename,data_read);
        }
    );
}, 4);

var files = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

for (var file in files) {
    q.push({filename:file+".txt"}, function (err,filename,res) {
        console.log(filename + " read");
    });
}
```

You can see that each file is added to the queue (console.log filename), but only when the current queue is under the limit you set previously.

async.queue get information about availability of the queue through a callback, this callback is called only when data file is read and any action you have to do is achieved. (see fileRead method)

So you cannot be overwhelmed by files descriptor.

```
> node ./queue.js
0.txt
    1.txt
2.txt
0.txt read
3.txt
3.txt read
4.txt
2.txt read
5.txt
4.txt read
6.txt
5.txt read
7.txt
    1.txt read (biggest file than other)
8.txt
6.txt read
9.txt
7.txt read
8.txt read
9.txt read
```

Answer (score 10):

You're reading too many files. Node reads files asynchronously, it'll be reading all files at once. So you're probably reading the 10240 limit.

See if this works:

```
var fs = require('fs')
var events = require('events')
var util = require('util')
var path = require('path')

var FsPool = module.exports = function(dir) {
    events.EventEmitter.call(this)
    this.dir = dir;
    this.files = [];
    this.active = [];
    this.threads = 1;
    this.on('run', this.runQuta.bind(this))
};
// So will act like an event emitter
util.inherits(FsPool, events.EventEmitter);

FsPool.prototype.runQuta = function() {
    if(this.files.length === 0 && this.active.length === 0) {
        return this.emit('done');
    }
    if(this.active.length < this.threads) {
        var name = this.files.shift()

        this.active.push(name)
        var fileName = path.join(this.dir, name);
        var self = this;
        fs.stat(fileName, function(err, stats) {
            if(err)
                throw err;
            if(stats.isFile()) {
                fs.readFile(fileName, function(err, data) {
                    if(err)
                        throw err;
                    self.active.splice(self.active.indexOf(name), 1)
                    self.emit('file', name, data);
                    self.emit('run');

                });
            } else {
                self.active.splice(self.active.indexOf(name), 1)
                self.emit('dir', name);
                self.emit('run');
            }
        });
    }
    return this
};
FsPool.prototype.init = function() {
    var dir = this.dir;
    var self = this;
    fs.readdir(dir, function(err, files) {
        if(err)
            throw err;
        self.files = files
        self.emit('run');
    })
    return this
};
var fsPool = new FsPool(__dirname)

fsPool.on('file', function(fileName, fileData) {
    console.log('file name: ' + fileName)
    console.log('file data: ', fileData.toString('utf8'))

})
fsPool.on('dir', function(dirName) {
    console.log('dir name: ' + dirName)

})
fsPool.on('done', function() {
    console.log('done')
});
fsPool.init()
```

Answer (score 10):

I ran into this problem today, and finding no good solutions for it, I created a module to address it. I was inspired by @fbartho's snippet, but wanted to avoid overwriting the fs module.

The module I wrote is [Filequeue](https://github.com/treygriffith/filequeue), and you use it just like fs:

```
var Filequeue = require('filequeue');
var fq = new Filequeue(200); // max number of files to open at once

fq.readdir('/Users/xaver/Downloads/xaver/xxx/xxx/', function(err, files) {
    if(err) {
        throw err;
    }
    files.forEach(function(file) {
        fq.readFile('/Users/xaver/Downloads/xaver/xxx/xxx/' + file, function(err, data) {
            // do something here
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6):

I solved this by updating watchman

```
 brew install watchman
```

Answer (score 4):

I just finished writing a little snippet of code to solve this problem myself, all of the other solutions appear way too heavyweight and require you to change your program structure.

This solution just stalls any fs.readFile or fs.writeFile calls so that there are no more than a set number in flight at any given time.

```
// Queuing reads and writes, so your nodejs script doesn't overwhelm system limits catastrophically
global.maxFilesInFlight = 100; // Set this value to some number safeish for your system
var origRead = fs.readFile;
var origWrite = fs.writeFile;

var activeCount = 0;
var pending = [];

var wrapCallback = function(cb){
    return function(){
        activeCount--;
        cb.apply(this,Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
        if (activeCount < global.maxFilesInFlight && pending.length){
            console.log("Processing Pending read/write");
            pending.shift()();
        }
    };
};
fs.readFile = function(){
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    if (activeCount < global.maxFilesInFlight){
        if (args[1] instanceof Function){
            args[1] = wrapCallback(args[1]);
        } else if (args[2] instanceof Function) {
            args[2] = wrapCallback(args[2]);
        }
        activeCount++;
        origRead.apply(fs,args);
    } else {
        console.log("Delaying read:",args[0]);
        pending.push(function(){
            fs.readFile.apply(fs,args);
        });
    }
};

fs.writeFile = function(){
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    if (activeCount < global.maxFilesInFlight){
        if (args[1] instanceof Function){
            args[1] = wrapCallback(args[1]);
        } else if (args[2] instanceof Function) {
            args[2] = wrapCallback(args[2]);
        }
        activeCount++;
        origWrite.apply(fs,args);
    } else {
        console.log("Delaying write:",args[0]);
        pending.push(function(){
            fs.writeFile.apply(fs,args);
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: U should make a repo for this on github.

Comment: This works very well if graceful-fs is not working for you.

Answer (score 1):

With bagpipe, you just need change

```
FS.readFile(filename, onRealRead);
```

=>

```
var bagpipe = new Bagpipe(10);

bagpipe.push(FS.readFile, filename, onRealRead))
```

The bagpipe help you limit the parallel. more details: https://github.com/JacksonTian/bagpipe

Comment: It's all on chinese or other asian language. Is there any documentation written in english?

Comment: @FatihArslan English doc is available now.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem when running the *nodemon* command so i reduced the name of files open in *sublime text* and the error dissappeared.

Comment: I, too, was getting `EMFILE` errors and through trial and error noticed that closing some *Sublime* windows resolved the issue. I still don't know why. I tried adding `ulimit -n 2560` to my .bash_profile, but that didn't solve the issue. Does this indicate a need to change to *Atom* instead?

Answer (score 1):

[cwait](https://github.com/charto/cwait) is a general solution for limiting concurrent executions of any functions that return promises.

In your case the code could be something like:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var cwait = require('cwait');

// Allow max. 10 concurrent file reads.
var queue = new cwait.TaskQueue(Promise, 10);
var read = queue.wrap(Promise.promisify(batchingReadFile));

Promise.map(files, function(filename) {
    console.log(filename);
    return(read(filename));
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on @blak3r's answer, here's a bit of shorthand I use in case it helps other diagnose:

If you're trying to debug a Node.js script that is running out of file descriptors here's a line to give you the output of `lsof` used by the node process in question:

```
openFiles = child_process.execSync(`lsof -p ${process.pid}`);
```

This will synchronously run `lsof` filtered by the current running Node.js process and return the results via buffer.

Then use `console.log(openFiles.toString())` to convert the buffer to a string and log the results.

Answer (score 1):

For **nodemon** users:
Just use the **--ignore** flag to solve the problem.

Example:

```
nodemon app.js --ignore node_modules/ --ignore data/
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the latest `fs-extra`.

I had that problem on `Ubuntu` (16 and 18) with plenty of file/socket-descriptors space (count with `lsof |wc -l`). Used `fs-extra` version `8.1.0`. After the update to `9.0.0` the "Error: EMFILE, too many open files" vanished.

I've experienced diverse problems on diverse OS' with node handling filesystems. Filesystems are obviously not trivial.

Answer (score 1):

There's another possibility that hasn't been considered or discussed in any of the answers so far: **symbolic link cycles**.

Node's recursive filesystem watcher does not appear to detect and handle cycles of symlinks. So you can easily trigger this error with an arbitrarily high `nfiles` ulimit by simply running:

```sh
mkdir a
mkdir a/b
cd a/b 
ln -s .. c
```

GNU `find` will notice the symlink cycle and abort:

```
$ find a -follow
a
a/b
find: File system loop detected; ‘a/b/c’ is part of the same file system loop as ‘a’.
```

but node won't. If you set up a watch on the tree, it'll spew a `EMFILE, too many open files` error.

Amongst other things this can happen in `node_modules` where there's a containment relationship:

```
parent/
  package.json
  child/
    package.json
```

which is how I encountered it in a project I was trying to build.

Comment: did you happen to find fix that let you keep the symlinks?

Comment: @Rilcon42 I landed up just bypassing node-ts and avoiding the watcher. So no.

Answer (score 0):

I did installing watchman, changing limit etc. and it didn't work in Gulp.

Restarting iterm2 actually helped though.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that might still be looking for solutions, using async-await worked fine for me:

```
fs.readdir(<directory path></directory>, async (err, filenames) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }

    try {
        for (let filename of filenames) {
            const fileContent = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                fs.readFile(<dirctory path + filename>, 'utf-8', (err, content) => {
                    if (err) {
                        reject(err);
                    }
                    resolve(content);
                });
            });
            ... // do things with fileContent
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my two cents: Considering a CSV file is just lines of text I've ***streamed*** the data (strings) to avoid this problem.

Easiest solution for me that worked in my usecase.

It can be used with graceful fs or standard fs. Just note that there won't be headers in the file when creating.

```
// import graceful-fs or normal fs
const fs = require("graceful-fs"); // or use: const fs = require("fs") 

// Create output file and set it up to receive streamed data
// Flag is to say "append" so that data can be recursively added to the same file 
let fakeCSV = fs.createWriteStream("./output/document.csv", {
  flags: "a",
});
```

and the data that needs to be streamed to the file i've done like this

```
// create custom streamer that can be invoked when needed
const customStreamer = (dataToWrite) => {
  fakeCSV.write(dataToWrite + "\n");
};
```

Note that the dataToWrite is simply a string with a custom seperator like ";" or ",".
i.e.

```
const dataToWrite = "batman" + ";" + "superman"
customStreamer(dataToWrite);
```

This writes "batman;superman" to the file.

---

- *Note that there's no error catching or whatsoever in this example.*
- Docs: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options

Answer (score 0):

This will probably fix your problem if you're struggling to deploy a React solution that was created with the Visual Studio template (and has a web.config). In Azure Release Pipelines, **when selecting the template, use:**

**Azure App Service deployment**

Instead of:

**Deploy a Node.js app to Azure App Service**

It worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Note that you don't necessarily need to overcomplicate this issue, trying again works just fine.

```
import { promises as fs } from "fs";

const filepaths = [];
const errors = [];

function process_file(content: string) {
    // logic here
}

await Promise.all(
    filepaths.map(function read_each(filepath) {
        return fs
            .readFile(filepath, "utf8")
            .then(process_file)
            .catch(function (error) {
                if (error.code === "EMFILE") return read_each(filepath);
                else errors.push({ file: filepath, error });
            });
    }),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you did is almost right:

```
sysctl -w kern.maxfiles=20480
```

On my macOS, the default is 491520 where what you were setting is actually lower value than of my system default, I just set it to 999999 and it worked perfectly. No more of that error.

*Edit*: I forgot to mention to restart afterwards.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue, and i solved it by running `npm update` and it worked.

In some cases you may need to remove node_modules `rm -rf node_modules/`

Answer (score -1):

On Windows, there is seems that no the `ulimit` command to increase the number of open files. In `graceful-fs`, it maintains a queue to run I/O operations, eg: read/write file.

However, `fs.readFile, fs.writeFile` are based on `fs.open`, so you will need open/close files manually to solve this error.

```js
import fs from 'fs/promises';

const fd = await fs.open('path-to-file', 'r');

await fd.readFile('utf-8'); // <== read through file handle
await fd.close();           // <== manually close it
```

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/133122/ulimit-for-windows

Comment: calling "close" does not fix the issue. the file does not get immediately released. this can happen even when writing files, which should immediately close.

Answer (score -2):

This may happen after changing the Node version
ERR emfile too many open files

- Restart the computer
- brew install watchman

It should be absolutely fixed the issue

Comment: Installing watchman solved my issue

Answer (score -2):

first update your version of expo using `expo update` and then run `yarn / npm install`. This solved the issue for me!