# NodeJS error "EMFILE, too many open files" on Mac OS

Tags: macos, node.js

For sometime I am having the following error:

```
Error: EMFILE, too many open files  '/Users/blagus/Gallery/Websites/Nicsware/Pills/resources/core/auth.node.js'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:427:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:284:15)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:473:44)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at instController  (/Users/blagus/Gallery/Websites/Nicsware/Pills/engine/mvc.node.js:79:31)
    at init (/Users/blagus/Gallery/Websites/Nicsware/Pills/engine/mvc.node.js:57:8)
    at route (/Users/blagus/Gallery/Websites/Nicsware/Pills/engine/dispatcher.node.js:268:36)
```

The line of code making the call to this file (mvc.node.js:79) is

```
    this.currentRoute.class = require( controllerFile )[dispatchClass].bind( this );
```

(it is a framework I am creating)

As you can see, the file auth.node.js is called by a REQUIRE, so the given solutions with gracefullFS and similar does not fit. Besides, this problem occour MacOS only. In a Ubuntu seems to work just fine.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is `auth.node.js` doing something strange? If I generate a stacktrace when I require a JS file, `fs.*` doesn't show up.

Comment: Well, at a Linux box it behaves just fine. Besides is just a simple require that give me trouble

Comment: Looking at the stack trace, the problem isn't caused by the `require` itself but by the module that you're requiring. Then again, if you don't post code it's just a guess...

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can solve this problem by increasing the `maxfiles` limit:

```
launchctl limit maxfiles 16384 16384 && ulimit -n 16384
```

Comment: I won't downvote as this answer is technically correct, but also very dangerous, especially as since Lion the default amount of simultaneous files is along the 10000 mark, setting the limit this low on a running machine can render all open programs unusable in a second. Let's suggest 16384 instead of 2048 instead if we're trying to bump UP the amount

Comment: Well, this fixed the issue for me, no more `Error: EMFILE, too many open files` ! Thank you. 
Also, not sure of what I'm doing, but it works. 
I would be glad to know the *real* issue behind this problem, why does node pops out this error message. 

Thank you anyway.

Comment: I agree w Igor; I am not sure increasing the limit is an acceptable answer for some as this a security risk. I think in reality at some point gulp needs to "let go" of the stream of files. One way to do this is chain some of your gulp tasks via shell scripting . Yes this seems odd but what is the alternative in gulp? She'll or npm tasks/scripts via npm run.

Comment: This works well for me but I need to do it after every restart. Is there a way to make it permanent?

Comment: The ulimit value was too large. It threw an error `-bash: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Invalid argument`. So, I reduced it to 8192. Works fine now.

Comment: if you add it into ~/.bashrc

'launchctl limit maxfiles 16384 16384 && ulimit -n 16384'

it will be permanent, (bashrc is ran everytime you start a terminal (bash) session

Comment: You have to put sudo at the beginning. It didn't work until I added sudo

Comment: This did not seem to do anything for me.

Answer (score 58):

This worked for me:

```
ulimit -n 10480
```

[found here](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy/issues/21#issuecomment-10840100)

Comment: as Ryan mentioned below. the default limit is 256. setting it to 10480 is probably overkill. Bump it up incrementally `ulimit -n 360`

Comment: Thanks Lane as well :) anyone know how to kill the processes or close the opened files ?

Answer (score 21):

i had this error and the ulimit and launchclt didn't work for me,

this solution from http://yabfog.com/blog/2014/10/22/yosemite-upgrade-changes-open-file-limit worked for me

```
echo kern.maxfiles=65536 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
echo kern.maxfilesperproc=65536 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
sudo sysctl -w kern.maxfiles=65536
sudo sysctl -w kern.maxfilesperproc=65536
ulimit -n 65536 65536
```

and then putting the

```
ulimit -n 65536 65536
```

into `~/.bashrc`

Comment: should mention it's a hacky solution but one to helps out when your local machine isn't working well

Answer (score 20):

I am using `watchman`. Which fixed this error for me. Worth trying!!!

```
brew update
brew install watchman
```

---

It watches the files and documents and triggers file handling events if there are any changes. Here's their github repo:

- https://github.com/facebook/watchman

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me, on Catalina 10.15.1.

Comment: Catalina 10.15.3 here as well - only solution that worked

Comment: Can you provide some context as to how this works? Posting two installation commands is not helpful.

Comment: Hi @Contrapak 
As the name says, it just watches the files and documents. Triggers file handling events if there are any changes. Please look into their github repo for better understanding.
https://github.com/facebook/watchman

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me.

Comment: @bh4r4th re how it works, i'm curious why when I have homebrew auto updates enabled, and watchman installed, i regularly have to "reinstall" it (thinking I don't have it) but then in output I see it's merely being upgraded.... any idea?

Answer (score 8):

Your code is opening too many files. By default, OS X has a limit of 256 simultaneously opened files. When your code requires a new module, node has to open the file to read it in. If you are already at this limit, node's require cannot continue and will throw an Error. You should audit places in your application where you are calling fs.open and ensuring that you are properly closing all of those files. You may also encounter this problem if you attempt to do too many simultaneous file system reads, since each pending read will be an open file. I have also encountered this problem while using fs.watchFile, which also requires opening a handle to the file.

Comment: Do you have any resources to make sure I'm doing what you mentioned? I would prefer to practice better usage of fs instead of just having to keep upping the limit as others have suggested.

Answer (score 7):

Check your ulimit. For example initialy my ulimit on OSX was 256.

- Run `ulimit -n` to see the limit.
- Afterwards You can `ulimit -n 1024` to set a higher limit.

Answer (score 6):

None of the other answers worked for me. This did the trick:

```
launchctl limit maxfiles 16384 16384
```

Also to note, this doesn't save across sessions so unless you want to run it for each bash terminal session I suggest putting the above line in your ~/.bashrc (or ~/.zshrc if you are using zsh) by doing this at the command line:

```
vi ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 2):

ulimit is great if you are using the terminal but it only works if you are running your app from the same terminal tab ( or shell instance ).  Launchctl is great but is systemwide. If you leave Launchctl limit maxfile alone, the soft limit is 256 and the hard limit is unlimited.

In a production environment, you will probably need to launch at startup and reboot on crash, which means the best answer for Mac OSX is to use a .plist file for each of your applications.  I launch my node application using said plist file ( which runs at start up and reboots after crashing )... inside this file you can set the amount of files **per application** using the `SoftResourcesLimit` key.

```
<key>KeepAlive</key>
<true/>

<key>RunAtLoad</key>
<true/>

<key>SoftResourceLimits</key>
<dict>
<key>NumberOfFiles</key>
  <integer>16384</integer>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maximum files was reseted to `256` in OS X 10.10.3 Yosemite. This can lead to problems with npm installations. You can check this limit from terminal with command `ulimit -n`. In order to change this beyond `256`, you need to create two configuration files.

The first property list file `/Library/LaunchDaemons/limit.maxfiles.plist` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
 <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
      <key>Label</key>
        <string>limit.maxfiles</string>
      <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
          <string>launchctl</string>
          <string>limit</string>
          <string>maxfiles</string>
          <string>65536</string>
          <string>65536</string>
        </array>
      <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
      <key>ServiceIPC</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
  </plist>
```

The second property list file `/Library/LaunchDaemons/limit.maxproc.plist` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple/DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
  <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
      <key>Label</key>
        <string>limit.maxproc</string>
      <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
          <string>launchctl</string>
          <string>limit</string>
          <string>maxproc</string>
          <string>2048</string>
          <string>2048</string>
        </array>
      <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true />
      <key>ServiceIPC</key>
        <false />
    </dict>
  </plist>
```

Set the proper ownership and rights:

```
sudo chown root:wheel /Library/LaunchDaemons/limit.maxfiles.plist
sudo chown root:wheel /Library/LaunchDaemons/limit.maxproc.plist
sudo chmod 644 /Library/LaunchDaemons/limit.maxfiles.plist
sudo chmod 644 /Library/LaunchDaemons/limit.maxproc.plist
```

Set the desired limits to bash profile file (`.bashrc` or `.bashprofile` or similar):

```
ulimit -n 65536
ulimit -u 2048
```

Make sure that the rights are the same for bash profile:

```
chmod 644 .your_bash_profile_file
```

Restart computer and check with `ulimit -n` max files. It should be `65536` and you should be able to change it anything below that.

> Source: http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/tuning/open-files-limit/#Mac-OS-X

Answer (score 0):

awongh's answer worked for me

```
ulimit -n 10480
```

But only after starting an interactive shell

```
sudo -i
```

Outside of the shell I kept getting a permission error on OSX Yosemite

Answer (score 0):

As for other questions about EMFILE error, you have to manage a queue to limit number of files opened at the same time. Increasing limit will only delay your problem.

There is some responses there : [node and Error: EMFILE, too many open files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965606/node-and-error-emfile-too-many-open-files)

Answer (score 0):

You need to reinstall watchman and make sure that brew's version is the one that's gonna be used in the terminal. Just follow these steps in order to do it:

```sh
brew update
brew install watchman
brew link --overwrite watchman
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

None of the above solutions work on Mac M1 chip.
If you face above issue and can't make it work - the solution is to go to eBay and buy used Intel based MacBook - can get one for around $300.