# EMFILE error on Mac when running Meteor app

Tags: node.js, meteor

I can get my meteor app to successfully build and start by running

```
meteor
=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.
=> Started your app.

=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/
```

However when I kill the app with Ctrl+C, I get the following stack dump:

```
^C
fs.js:439
  return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
                 ^
Error: EMFILE, too many open files '/Users/alex/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.1j76dru++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/static-assets/server/shell-server.js'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:439:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:290:15)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:473:44)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at /tools/runners/run-app.js:141:7
    at /Users/alex/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.1j76dru++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/tool-env/cleanup.js:24:7
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/alex/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.1j76dru++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
    at /Users/alex/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.1j76dru++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/tool-env/cleanup.js:23:7
    at Object.exports.noYieldsAllowed (/Users/alex/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.1j76dru++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:73:14)
    at runHandlers (/Users/alex/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.1j76dru++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/tool-env/cleanup.js:20:16)
    at process.<anonymous> (/Users/alex/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.1j76dru++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/tool-env/cleanup.js:32:5)
    at process.g (events.js:180:16)
    at process.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at Signal.wrap.onsignal (node.js:790:46)
```

I can't trace this error to a specific point in my code, since no where in this stack trace does it point to a line of code I have written.

How might I go fixing this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19981065/nodejs-error-emfile-too-many-open-files-on-mac-os ??

Comment: The comment by Sasikanth solved the problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19981065/nodejs-error-emfile-too-many-open-files-on-mac-os