# stencil bundle command doesn't work

Tags: bigcommerce

I have a theme that I was downloaded from marketplace.

Everything works fine in my machine, but when I first tried to run `stencil bundle` it throws me this error:

```
$ stencil bundle
Validating theme...
SCSS Parsing Started...
Template Parsing Started...
Language Files Parsing Started...
Building Theme Schema File...
Generating Manifest Started...
JavaScript Bundling Started...
ok -- Language Files Parsing Finished
ok -- SCSS Parsing Finished
ok -- Manifest Generation Finished
failed  -- EMFILE: too many open files, open 'C:\xampp\htdocs\ct\firestoreonline\peak-bc\templates\pages\account\orders\invoice.html'
C:\Users\velho\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@bigcommerce\stencil-cli\lib\stencil-bundle.js:78
            throw err;
            ^

Error: EMFILE: too many open files, open 'C:\xampp\htdocs\ct\firestoreonline\peak-bc\templates\pages\account\orders\invoice.html'
    at Error (native)
```

I also stopped all terminal proccess before run `stencil bundle`. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Try deleting AppData/Roaming/*/npm_modules and removing assets/js/bundle.js from the theme - then do a fresh npm install -g bigcommerce/stencil-cli

Comment: you can also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19981065/nodejs-error-emfile-too-many-open-files-on-mac-os

Answer (score 1):

The fix has been merged. You can pull down a copy of the latest cornerstone files from github or you can wait for the next cornerstone theme release.

Thanks for the report

https://github.com/bigcommerce/stencil-cli/pull/337