Running "npx expo start" on MacOS terminal and getting Error: EMFILE: too many open files, watch
I am trying to run my React Native application using npx expo start and I am getting the following error message on my terminal:

Your macOS system limit does not allow enough watchers for Metro, install Watchman instead. Learn more: https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/install
Error: EMFILE: too many open files, watch


I have already installed watchman using the following command brew install watchman and my current Node.js is installed to the latest version (22.12.0). I just updated Node.js to the latest version (it was previously on version 18). Please ask for further details.

Take a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19981065/nodejs-error-emfile-too-many-open-files-on-mac-os

I believe that it might be a problem to do with how watchman is installed on my Mac, I was having issues with installing one of the libraries. Currently one of my React Native projects is working so I am using that one.
