# EMFILE, too many open file

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, mean-stack, filehandler

```
[INFO] system - { codeblock: 'catch copy image', error: { [Error: EMFILE, too many open files './uploads/54f911bad366ed/document/document_559dfb750f15617.png']
 errno: 20,
 code: 'EMFILE',
 path: './uploads/54f911bad366ed/document/document_559dfb750f15617.png',
 syscall: 'open' } }
```

Regret I don't have enough reputation to make comment in this thread ([node and Error: EMFILE, too many open files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965606/node-and-error-emfile-too-many-open-files))  so I have to create a new one to ask question.

My application has above error.  I checked the log and the error occurred during a copying process (of template to user's login account and an admin account) when users first login.

I don't know idea why because it also occurred on some users account that the user did not login.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you post the code snippet

Comment: @Shrey i'm trying to post it to plunker and share it here.  Will do it today

Comment: Possible duplicate of [node and Error: EMFILE, too many open files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965606/node-and-error-emfile-too-many-open-files)