# Node.js - Best bet to read a lot of PNG images into arrays?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image-processing, png, game-development

for my javascript game project, I'd like to make a 2 dimensional array that checks a PNG image for the color red and then saves tile-wise "true" or "false".

So I made something like this:

```
var array = new Array(100);

for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
array[i] = new Array(100);
}
```

First I only found a lot of canvas use cases, but because I am working in app.js (aka my node.js server application), I don't have access to the canvas (well I can use canvas on client side, but that
brings a lot of cheating possibilites with it!)
So I looked into node modules I could use, and I found [jimp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp) which I tried using.
There are some issues though.
First I encountered a similar error to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965606/node-and-error-emfile-too-many-open-files), but for some reason it fixed itself after changing
the code.

I feel like JIMP isn't the 100% correct solution for my problem though, does node maybe have some default file reading system I can use?

All I really need is a function like

```
function getPixel(x, y){
return pixelColor('./client/img/map.png', x, y).red;
}
```

Which I can then use to iterate through my arrays and save the RGB value of red into the array.
I feel like I did a really poor job on phrasing what I want to achieve and where my problems are,
I hope somebody might be able to help me anyways if not, please ask me for more information if you
feel like this is an easy task.

Edit 1: My title says "a lot of images" because my game is split into chunks, and every chunk = "background"-picture of the map, which equates to 1 896x896 file of "tile collisions". My application will need to read like 900 images to get the complete collision data into the array.

Comment: *does node maybe have some default file reading system I can use* you mean like `const fs = require('fs')` and now `fs` has a bunch of methods like `readFile` etc? Of course, then you need to decode the png file ... are you able to do that?

Comment: from a design point of view, the problem with your ideal function `pixelColor('./client/img/map.png', x, y).red;` that would open the file, decode it, get the pixel, close the file for every pixel - you can imagine this would be very inefficient for reading even 2 pixels from the one file, let alone the 10,000 your code suggests, or the 802,000 your `896x896` your edit 1 suggests - and that's just one file - multiply that by 900 and you'll need hours to do what you want. What part of JIMP doesn't meet your requirements?

Comment: I don't really know how to decode the png file.

True, good point. So ideally I'd open the picture of a chunk and then iterate through all the tiles in it before opening the next picture.

Idk, I feel like I don't really get how to use JIMP and the things Im trying to do aren't documented well enough. I run into errors calling functions and I can't seem to find my errors.