# Azure devops pipeline for nextjs application

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, next.js

I am trying to deploy a nextjs application on azure with azure devops project.
When I run the build pipeline all the steps are succeeded, but in release I get the error

```
Error: EMFILE: too many open files, open 'D:\a\_temp\temp_web_package_24483164492399134\node_modules\core-js\library\modules\es6.date.to-primitive.js'
```

I have added web.config file but still no luck

Comment: We can't help you without to know your process. can you share your release pipeline?

Comment: Could you specify which task in your pipeline throw above error? I check about this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965606/node-and-error-emfile-too-many-open-files), it said if node.js open too many files in your code. EMFILE error will occur. Donot know if this is the cause for your case?