# ERROR: TypeError: Cannot read property '...' of undefined using .end() with fs.createwritestream()

Tags: node.js, promise, runtime-error, fs, createwritestream

### ERROR

- I get the error:
  **ERROR: TypeError: Cannot read property 'outstream_for_folders' of undefined**
- I don't understand why I am getting this error.  I added lots of error checking for 'undefined', but I still get the error, so I think it may have something to do with promises or the "batching-fs-writestream"  library.
- If you look at the output you can follow all the uses of the variable **'outstream_for_folders'**
- error is *caught* on lines; **~363~** and **~370~**

> Note: just search this page for "**~363**" or "**~370**" to quickly
> find the relevant code below;

### CONFIGURATION:

- I am using **node version 12**.  Unfortunately, I can not update the server to use a new version of node.
- I am using "**batching-fs-writestream**" version "1.0.3".  https://www.npmjs.com/package/batching-fs-writestream
- Runnable Code is available up on https://codesandbox.io/s/error-using-fs-createwritestream-end-2o5rnw?file=/main.js
- I added console.log() trace points to all uses of the variable outstream_for_folders

### Project Info

- This is a directory tree walker, that writes two output files;

1. md5_folders.ndjson holding all the folders found
2. md5_files.ndjson   holding all the folders found

- I need to use a stream, because this will eventually be run on a server with lots of files.
- later the output ndjson files will be processed by another app a second time to find duplicate files using md5 hash
- then another web app will present these duplicate file list to a web GUI app for the user to pick which duplicate files the user wants to delete or keep.

### Console output and ERRORS

```
sandbox@sse-sandbox-2o5rnw:/sandbox$ node main.js
~406      calling main()
~37      calling  outstream_for_files= batching(tempStr)
~63~     calling  outstream_for_files.on(error)...
~86      calling  outstream_for_files.on(finish)...
~393     calling processRecursiveFolder()
~363~ ERROR: TypeError: Cannot read property 'outstream_for_folders' of undefined
~367     calling outstream_for_files.end():
~370~ ERROR: TypeError: Cannot read property 'outstream_for_files' of undefined
~408      Exitting
~283     calling dan_output_json_to_Stream(outstream_for_files...
~120     calling  .write(...)
~283     calling dan_output_json_to_Stream(outstream_for_files...
~120     calling  .write(...)
~283     calling dan_output_json_to_Stream(outstream_for_files...
~120     calling  .write(...)
~283     calling dan_output_json_to_Stream(outstream_for_files...
~120     calling  .write(...)
~283     calling dan_output_json_to_Stream(outstream_for_files...
~120     calling  .write(...)
~283     calling dan_output_json_to_Stream(outstream_for_files...
~120     calling  .write(...)
~120     calling  .write(...)
~120     calling  .write(...)
~120     calling  .write(...)
~120     calling  .write(...)
~120     calling  .write(...)
~120     calling  .write(...)
~120     calling  .write(...)
~120     calling  .write(...)
sandbox@sse-sandbox-2o5rnw:/sandbox$
```

### main.js

```
//"use strict";
// see https://codesandbox.io/s/error-using-fs-createwritestream-end-2o5rnw?file=/main.js
const fs = require("fs");
const crypto = require("crypto");
//const stream = require('stream');
//const util = require('util');
const path = require("path");

const batching = require("batching-fs-writestream");

var dan_gs = {
  outstream_for_folders: null,
  outstream_for_files: null,
  last_id: 1,
  md5hashtable: ["n/a"],
  startdirPath: `${path.join(__dirname, "testdir")}`,
  pathToStreams: `${path.join(__dirname, "z_md5")}`
};
// =============== dan Utils =========================
//const dan_utils= require('./dan_utils');

function dan_init_output_Streams(gsArg) {
  var tempStr = "";
  try {
    if (!fs.existsSync(gsArg.pathToStreams)) {
      fs.mkdirSync(gsArg.pathToStreams, { recursive: true }, (err) => {
        console.log(
          "~28~ ERROR: cound not mkdirSync(" + gsArg.pathToStreams + ") :" + err
        );
        throw err;
      });
    }

    //console.log( `~34~ pathToStreams is ` + gsArg.pathToStreams );
    tempStr = `${path.join(gsArg.pathToStreams, "md5_folders.ndjson")}`;

    console.log("~37      calling  outstream_for_files= batching(tempStr) ");
    gsArg.outstream_for_folders = batching(tempStr);

    if (gsArg.outstream_for_folders === null) {
      console.log("~43~ outstream_for_folders is null() : ");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`~46~ ERROR: ` + err);
  }

  try {
    tempStr = `${path.join(gsArg.pathToStreams, "md5_files.ndjson")}`;
    //console.log( `~24~ tempStr is ` + tempStr );
    gsArg.outstream_for_files = batching(tempStr);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`~44~ ERROR: ` + err);
  }
  //    -----   -----   -----   -----   -----   -----   -----
  try {
    if (
      typeof gsArg.outstream_for_folders === "undefined" ||
      gsArg.outstream_for_folders === undefined ||
      gsArg.outstream_for_folders == null
    ) {
      console.log("~61~ ERROR: outstream_for_folders is undefined() : ");
    } else {
      console.log("~63~     calling  outstream_for_files.on(error)...");
      gsArg.outstream_for_folders.on("error", (err) => {
        console.log(`~65~ ERROR occured in outstream_for_folders  !` + err);
      });
    }

    gsArg.outstream_for_files.on("error", (err) => {
      console.log(`~70~ ERROR: occured in outstream_for_files  !` + err);
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`~73~ ERROR: ` + err);
  }

  //    -----   -----   -----   -----   -----   -----   -----
  // Once ndjson has flushed all data to the output stream, let's indicate done.
  try {
    if (
      typeof gsArg.outstream_for_folders === "undefined" ||
      gsArg.outstream_for_folders === undefined ||
      gsArg.outstream_for_folders == null
    ) {
      console.log("~84~ ERROR: outstream_for_folders is undefined() : ");
    } else {
      console.log("~86      calling  outstream_for_files.on(finish)...");
      gsArg.outstream_for_folders.on("finish", function () {
        console.log("~88 outstream_for_folders  Finished!");
        console.log("- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -");
      });
    }

    gsArg.outstream_for_files.on("finish", function () {
      console.log("~94 outstream_for_files Finished!");
      console.log("- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -");
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`~98~ ERROR: ` + err);
  }

  return gsArg;
}

async function dan_output_json_to_Stream(outstreamArg, jsonObjOrStr) {
  let tempJsonStr = "{}"; 
  try {
    //console.log( '~108 isobject(): ' + isObject(jsonObjOrStr)  + '  ' + typeof(jsonObjOrStr));

    if (isObject(jsonObjOrStr)) {
      tempJsonStr = JSON.stringify(jsonObjOrStr);
    } else if (
      typeof jsonObjOrStr === "string" ||
      jsonObjOrStr instanceof String
    ) {
      tempJsonStr = jsonObjOrStr;
    } else {
      console.log("~118~ ERROR:  " + typeof jsonObjOrStr);
    }

    console.log("~120     calling  .write(...)  ");
    outstreamArg.write(tempJsonStr);

  } catch (e) {
    console.log("~123~ ERROR: (outstreamArg.write(jsonObj)) " + e);
  }
}

function dan_create_json_for_folder(
  folderid,
  parentid,
  pathStr,
  foldernameStr,
  fs_stat_obj
) {
  let jsonObj = {
    folderid: folderid,
    pid: parentid,
    p: pathStr + "\\",
    n: foldernameStr,
    a: fs_stat_obj.atimeMs,
    m: fs_stat_obj.mtimeMs,
    b: fs_stat_obj.birthtimeMs,
    z: "01_init",
    x: ""
  };

  //let jsonStr = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
  //console.log ('\n~147~ jsonStr is ' + jsonStr );

  return jsonObj;
}

function dan_create_json_for_file(
  fileid,
  parentid,
  pathStr,
  filenameStr,
  md5_Str,
  sh256_Str,
  fs_stat_obj
) {
  let jsonObj = {
    fileid: fileid,
    pid: parentid,
    p: pathStr,
    n: filenameStr,
    size: fs_stat_obj.size,
    md5: md5_Str,
    sha: "",
    a: fs_stat_obj.atimeMs,
    m: fs_stat_obj.mtimeMs,
    b: fs_stat_obj.birthtimeMs,
    z: "01_init",
    x: "",
    dups: "",
    flag2Bdeleted: "F"
  };

  //let jsonStrjsonStr = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
  //console.log ('\n~181~ jsonStr is ' + jsonStr );

  return jsonObj;
}

function dan_calculateMD5(filePath) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let hash = crypto.createHash("md5");

    //console.log( `~190~ dan_calculateMD5( ` + filePath + ')'  );
    let stream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);

    stream.on("error", function (err) {
      reject(err);
    });

    stream.on("data", function (data) {
      hash.update(data, "utf8");
    });

    stream.on("end", function () {
      stream.close();

      // Return ( hash value in hex)
      resolve(hash.digest("hex"));
    });
  });
}

function dan_validateMD5(hash) {
  return RegExp("^[a-f0-9]{32}$", "gm").test(hash);
}

//https://codeburst.io/node-js-fs-module-write-streams-657cdbcc3f47

function isObject(objValue) {
  return (
    objValue && typeof objValue === "object" && objValue.constructor === Object
  );
}

// =============== end of dan Util =========================

// SEE  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66758627/calculating-md5-hashes-of-multiple-files
//
// also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827612/node-js-fs-readdir-recursive-directory-search/5827895#5827895
//
// for fs.stat() - https://www.brainbell.com/javascript/fs-stats-structure.html

//      npm install util
//      npm install path
//      npm install stream
//      npm install batching-fs-writestream
//
//      cd D:\Program Files\nodejs\dan_nodejs
//      node dan_dir_to_json.js

function processRecursiveFolder(parent_id, routePath) {
  //var fileName;

  fs.readdir(routePath, (err, files) => {
    // Get files in path
    files.forEach((item) => {
      let filePath = path.join(routePath, item); // Join root dir with path of folder
      //console.log ('\n~35~ filePath is ' + filePath );
      //console.log ('~36~ routePath is ' + routePath );
      //console.log ('~37~ item is ' + item );

      fs.stat(filePath, async (err, stat) => {
        // Get stats of dir

        //console.log ('\n~80~ fs.stat() is ' + JSON.stringify(stat) );

        if (stat.isDirectory()) {
          // If dir is folder, run recursively
          try {
            //console.log (`\n~83~ DIR: $(routePath) is a directory, recurse`);
            dan_gs.last_id = dan_gs.last_id + 1;
            let tempJsonObj1 = dan_create_json_for_folder(
              dan_gs.last_id,
              parent_id,
              routePath,
              item,
              stat
            );
            let tempJsonStr1 = JSON.stringify(tempJsonObj1) + "\n";
            //console.log( "~62~" + tempJsonStr );

            if (
              dan_gs.outstream_for_folders === undefined ||
              typeof dan_gs.outstream_for_folders === "undefined" ||
              dan_gs.outstream_for_folders == null
            ) {
              console.log(
                "~279~ ERROR: outstream_for_folders is undefined() : "
              );
            } else {
              console.log(
                "~283     calling dan_output_json_to_Stream(outstream_for_files..."
              );
              dan_output_json_to_Stream(
                dan_gs.outstream_for_folders,
                tempJsonStr1
              );
            }

            processRecursiveFolder(dan_gs.last_id, filePath);
          } catch (err) {
            console.log(`~72~ ERROR: ` + err);
          }
        } else {
          // Continue

          let fileName = path
            .basename(filePath)
            .replace(path.extname(filePath), ""); // Get fileName without extension
          //console.log ('\n~89~ ' + item + ' is a file, calc MD5  ' + fileName );

          await dan_calculateMD5(filePath)
            .then(function (fileHash) {
              if (dan_validateMD5(fileHash)) {
                try {
                  dan_gs.last_id = dan_gs.last_id + 1;
                  //console.log('\n~88 File: ' + filePath );
                  //console.log('\n~88 Hash: ~IS~ ' + fileHash );

                  let tempJsonObj2 = dan_create_json_for_file(
                    dan_gs.last_id,
                    parent_id,
                    routePath,
                    item,
                    fileHash,
                    "",
                    stat
                  );

                  let tempJsonStr2 = JSON.stringify(tempJsonObj2) + "\n";
                  //console.log( "~94~" + tempJsonStr );

                  dan_output_json_to_Stream(
                    dan_gs.outstream_for_files,
                    tempJsonStr2
                  );

                  dan_gs.md5hashtable.push(fileHash);
                } catch (err) {
                  console.log(`~100~ ERROR: ` + err);
                }
              } else {
                throw new Error(
                  "~103~ ERROR: Unable to calculate hash for file: " +
                    fileName +
                    "\nError: " +
                    fileHash +
                    "\n"
                );
              }
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
              throw new Error("~107~ ERROR: " + err + "\n");
            });
        }
      });
    });
  });
}

function dan_close_output_Streams(gsArg) {
  //    -----   -----   -----   -----   -----   -----   -----
  // Once we've written each record in the record-set, we have to end the stream so that
  // the  stream knows to flush and close the file output stream

  try {
    if (
      typeof gsArg.outstream_for_folders === "undefined" ||
      gsArg.outstream_for_folders === undefined ||
      gsArg.outstream_for_folders == null
    ) {
      console.log("~357~ ERROR: outstream_for_folders is undefined() : ");
    } else {
      console.log("~359~ calling outstream_for_files.end() : ");
      gsArg.outstream_for_folders.end();
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`~363~ ERROR: ` + err);
  }

  try {
    console.log("~367     calling outstream_for_files.end() : ");
    gsArg.outstream_for_files.end();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`~370~ ERROR: ` + err);
  }
}

// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
// - - - - - - - -      main()       - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
async function main() {
  try {
    dan_gs = dan_init_output_Streams(dan_gs);

    if (
      typeof dan_gs.outstream_for_folders === "undefined" ||
      dan_gs.outstream_for_folders === undefined ||
      dan_gs.outstream_for_folders == null
    ) {
      console.log("~386~ ERROR: outstream_for_folders is undefined() : ");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`~389~ ERROR: ` + err);
  }

  try {
    console.log("~393     calling processRecursiveFolder()");
    processRecursiveFolder(100001, dan_gs.startdirPath);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`~400~ ERROR: ` + err);
  }

  try {
    dan_close_output_Streams();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`~402~ ERROR: ` + err);
  }
}

console.log("~406      calling main()");
main();
console.log("~408      Exitting");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the function `dan_close_output_Streams` with an undefined (missing) argument. To fix, go to line 401 and change

```js
dan_close_output_Streams();
```

with

```js
dan_close_output_Streams(dan_gs);
```

Comment: thank you.  I come from a compiled and Visual basic background, and am still getting used to JavaScript's untyped and interpretive nature.

This poses another QUESTION: is there a build module or build method in codesandbox.io that would give Warnings on "optional parameters" that are NOT check for undefined? Would eslint have given a better understandable warning?

Comment: SOLUTION: actually this is not a solution per se, just that if someone in the future comes across this post, I think the following would help them.  
Because the error variable `outstream_for_folders` was inside the object `gsArg.` as in `gsArg.outstream_for_folders.end();`.  On line 351, I should have added the following code to help in my debugging hunt; 
`if (typeof gsArg === "undefined") {
      console.log("~356~ ERROR: gsArg is undefined() : ");
    } else if (
      typeof gsArg.outstream_for_folders === "undefined"      
`

Comment: I posted the DEBUGGING SOLUTION that shows a better error, at [https://codesandbox.io/s/error-using-fs-createwritestream-end-fixed-zhjz04?file=/main.js:10307-10783](https://codesandbox.io/s/error-using-fs-createwritestream-end-fixed-zhjz04?file=/main.js:10307-10783)