# Why it says application failed to deploy on AWS - Serverless

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

When I trying to deploy my application it is failing to deploy application. In the first stages of the application there wasn't a such an issue it work properly.

```
× Stack wb-slack-game-local failed to deploy (63s)
Environment: win32, node 16.13.0, framework 3.7.5 (local) 3.7.1v (global), plugin 6.1.6, SDK 4.3.2
Credentials: Local, "serverlessUser" profile
Docs:        docs.serverless.com
Support:     forum.serverless.com
Bugs:        github.com/serverless/serverless/issues

Error:
Cannot read file node_modules\type-fest\source\require-at-least-one.d.ts due to: EMFILE: too many open files, open 'C:\Users\prabodha.lahiru\Desktop\LambdaFunc7\roastmeslackapp\node_modules\type-fest\source\require-at-least-one.d.ts'
```

What I tried,

- I tried rebooting system and again run the vs code
- Externally open the terminal and tried to run application
- Changed serverless version

Nothing was successfull. And I could not find a solution in stackoverflow. I am using serverless frameworkversion 3.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965606/node-and-error-emfile-too-many-open-files

Comment: No. I was not able to run those commands in windows

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by using webpack. If you are facing the same issue try using [serverless-webpack plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-webpack).

```
Running "serverless" from node_modules

Deploying wb-slack-game to stage local (us-east-2)
Bundling with Webpack...
```